# Why does Spring MVC prefer to serve application/json types over anything else?

Tags: json, web-services, spring-mvc

Given the following Spring code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/somepath")
public class SomeService {
    @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ReturnType methodOne() {
        // stuff
    }

    @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=text/html")
    public ReturnType methodTwo() {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I've noticed that, when a client doesn't include an "Accept" header at all, the "application/json" method is always called in preference over the text/html method. My question is - why? There's nothing to choose between them, so why prefer one over the other? I would have expected an error message instead...

A concrete example:

```
@RequestMapping("/somepath")
@Controller
public class SomeService {

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> methodOne() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Method One", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=text/html")
    public ResponseEntity<String> methodTwo() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Method Two", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/xml")
    public ResponseEntity<String> methodThree() {
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Method Three", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

"Method One" is always output if there are no accept headers.

Comment: because generally apis are intended to get data going between client<->server. json is a data format, whereas html is intended for display only.

Comment: Interesting point - I tested by adding another method with a RequestMapping for an application/xml accept heading, because there should then be no reason to choose the json version over that (or vice-versa) and yet I still get the json version every time.

Comment: @AndyB the return type is determind by the request type.

Comment: But that's the point that I'm trying to make - if I don't set an accept header, there *is* no request type.

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't prefer anything. It can return whatever you specify (pdf, xml, etc)

However, JSON is commonly implented as views often interact with controllers using javascript and ajax. What data format is best to use with javascript : JSON.

Comment: Hmmm.... That doesn't seem to be quite true, though... There's no code in my example (or the surrounding config) to set up any specific JSON views. What you see is all that I've got - and yet it will use the application/json method every time in the absence of any other information.

Comment: @AndyB What isn't true ? You've set up the code to use JSON. I have no idea what yr views do. The methods posted do not return any data anyway.  But my point is its common in web applications for the client/view to use javascript to access data in JSON format, and that would explain why you say, incorrectly, that "spring prefers json".

Comment: Unless I've really misunderstood something about what I'm doing, I don't think that views are involved. I've added a more concrete example to my question - what you see is the entirety of the code. I'm testing this using a Java rest client that hits the service directly over HTTP, and if I don't set an accept header, I always get "Method One" as the response - I still don't see what's going on that would cause that behaviour.

Comment: instead of headers = "Accepts", etc. do consumes="application/json", might fix your issue.

Comment: @AndyB OK yes that makes sense, I understand now. But I don;t have an answer I'm afraid. It could even be simply calling the first one declared

Comment: Ah well, thanks for chatting about it. It's not the first one declared, I'm afraid - I've tried swapping the RequestMappings around, and it always goes for the application/json one.

Comment: @dardo - yes, it might (although I'd have to use produces), and to be fair, so would splitting out the services so that I have a controller that handles text/html and something separate for json - in practice, that's probably what I'd be doing anyway. But I'm still curious as to what the mechanics are - exactly what's going on to always resolve in the favour of json.